# Перси и персики: этимологическая связь

Tags: этимология

Слова "перси" и "персик" этимологически связаны, или это случайной созвучие?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово "персик" заимствовано через ср.-нж.-нем. *persik* или голл. *perzik, persik* из лат. *mālum persicum* "персидское яблоко" или *prunus persica* "персидская слива". В русском языке с конца XVII в. (1697). Первоисточник: др.-греч. прилагательное *περσικός* "персидский". Эллинистический мир некогда получил персиковое дерево из восточных областей Ирана. Родиной персикового дерева, однако, считают не Персию, а Китай.

"Перси" (др.-рус. *пьрсь*, ст.-слав. *прьсь*) восходит к праслав. **pьrsь*, родственному лит. *piršys* "грудь (у лошади)", далее из др.-инд. "ребро", авест. "ребро, бок", осет. *fars* "сторона, бок". С тем же корнем *наперсник*.

**Так, слова "персик" и "перси" этимологически не родственны.**

Источники:

- "Этимологический словарь современного русского языка" А. К. Шапошникова
- "Толковый словарь русского языка с включением сведений о происхождении слов" РАН